# How to use variables passed from view to template within conditions in templates django?

Tags: python, django

I have following view:-

```
def abc(request):
     context={
        'content_type': 1
       }
     responder=render(request,'home.html',context)
```

Now i need to use the value of content_type in my django template as follows:-

```
<div class="{% if {{content_type}} == 1 %}" abc {% endif %}></div>
```

Now i need to add the class abc only when content_type is 1.

I know that django does not allow nesting parentheses, so is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need extra parentheses inside:

```
<div class="{% if content_type == 1 %} abc {% endif %}"></div>
```

Comment: You just need to move the `"` - the OP got it wrong!

Comment: i was trying that, but was not sure so thought would ask here once; thanks